# Need validation of consistent result set with group by and having clause

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, having-clause

I have a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE `zpost` (
  `post_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `post_subject` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

With data set as

```
INSERT INTO `zpost` (`post_id`, `topic_id`, `post_subject`) VALUES
(44, 33, 'New topic by new user'),
(45, 33, 'Re: New topic by new user'),
(47, 33, 'Re: New topic by new user'),
(46, 34, 'New Topic by James on 1/2'),
(48, 35, 'Sep 29th new topic'),
(49, 35, 'Re: Sep 29th new topic'),
(50, 35, 'Re: Sep 29th new topic'),
(51, 36, 'Another Sep topic');
```

And indexes (not relevant to the question, but here)

```
ALTER TABLE `zpost`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  ADD KEY `topic_id` (`topic_id`);
```

And finally the SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `zpost` group by `topic_id` having min(`topic_id`);
```

Finally the output

```
|post_id|topic_id|post_subject              |
+-------+--------+--------------------------+
|     44|      33|New topic by new user     |
|     46|      34|New Topic by James on 1/2 |
|     48|      35|Sep 29th new topic        |
|     51|      36|Another Sep topic         |
```

I only want the minimum post_id for a given topic_id - the 1st topic record.  And I seem to get that by default.  Not sure if that is just the way the database decided to provide the rows or if this is a consistent order.  The database in question is MariaDB.  I have also tried to insert data in reverse order in the database as below

```
INSERT INTO `zpost` (`post_id`, `topic_id`, `post_subject`) VALUES
(51, 36, 'Another Sep topic'),
(50, 35, 'Re: Sep 29th new topic'),
(49, 35, 'Re: Sep 29th new topic'),
(48, 35, 'Sep 29th new topic'),
(46, 34, 'New Topic by James on 1/2'),
(47, 33, 'Re: New topic by new user'),
(45, 33, 'Re: New topic by new user'),
(44, 33, 'New topic by new user');
```

And I still get the results I want, which is great news and no further action needs to be taken.  But not sure why and for the sake of completeness if I wanted the last row (max post_id) how would I alter the SQL to get that row associated with each topic_id? One would think that changing min to max would take care of that, but no! I get the same result for this query as well.

```
SELECT * FROM `zpost` group by `topic_id` having max(`topic_id`);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in relational databases the rows in a table don't have any inherent ordering. It doesn't matter in which order you insert, update, or delete them. Tables represent **unordered bags** of rows.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want.

To get the older `post_id` for each `topic_id` you can do:

```
select post_id, topic_id, post_subject
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by topic_id order by post_id) as rn
  from zpost
) x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 post_id  topic_id  post_subject              
 -------- --------- ------------------------- 
 44       33        New topic by new user     
 46       34        New Topic by James on 1/2 
 48       35        Sep 29th new topic        
 51       36        Another Sep topic
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle - ASC](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXu8cXmYo6JtJ3Csyy8ZQB/1).

To get the newest `post_id` for each `topic_id` you can do:

```
select post_id, topic_id, post_subject
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by topic_id order by post_id desc) as rn
  from zpost
) x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 post_id  topic_id  post_subject              
 -------- --------- ------------------------- 
 47       33        Re: New topic by new user 
 46       34        New Topic by James on 1/2 
 50       35        Re: Sep 29th new topic    
 51       36        Another Sep topic
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle - DESC](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXu8cXmYo6JtJ3Csyy8ZQB/2).

Comment: You are absolutely right about RDBMS not having an inherent sorting.  However this is not really (output) sorting, and about how does it consistently choose the 1st topic row. The fact it does is interesting.  Of course a sub query can do it, but I want to keep this simple since simple already works.  The alternative subquery I wrote is: select post_id, topic_id, post_subject
from zpost where post_id in (
  select max(post_id) from zpost group by topic_id
)

Comment: @Senthil I don't understand how exactly your version of the query works, so I can't see how stable that solution is. Sometimes when the tables are small all the data resides in a single I/O block on disk, or the whole primary index does not span more than a single tree node; typically you see special behavior in these small cases, that you don't see once the engine starts using more blocks or nodes. I would be careful with this solution and I would test it with a much higher number of rows, specially after inserting and deleting many random rows.

Comment: Agree. Thanks much.